Reverse Coding Likert Data for Cronbach's Alpha
I am completing an exam whereby we were given Likert data in which 2 questions were negatively worded. The data contained missing values which are MCAR (listwise deletion isn't appropriate it loses 3/4th observations).
Prior to calculating Cronbach's alpha, I reverse-coded the negatively worded questions (code below).
This results in an alpha of -0.03, and an error which states half of the questions are negatively correlated with the first principal component.
Running the same code, without reverse coding the negative questions, results in an alpha of 0.6, and interpretable results for the the reliability assessments of each question being dropped.
I am asking for some advice on what may be causing this (whether it be the missing data, reverse coding) or an error with the scales of the initial data.
I have attached my code for reference:
# Reverse code Q2 and Q6
data[ , 2] = 6 - data[ , 2] # Question 2
data[ , 6] = 6 - data[ , 6] # Question 6

Calculate Cronbach's Alpha
CronbachAlpha(data[,2:10], cond=TRUE , conf.level=0.95) 
Cronbach's alpha=NA as there is missing data
Psych package for cronbachs alpha finds pairwise correlations for missing data by default
library(psych)
psych::alpha(data[,2:12])

Although questions 2 and 6 were reverse coded, it appears that Q1, Q2, Q3 and Q6 correlated with first PC, and were advised to be reverse coded.

Are you sure they weren't already reversed? Also what package is CronbachAlpha from?

Likert is a name, it's not an acronym.

They were not, but we have only been told that they are negatively worded. CronbachAlpha is from the DescTools package.

For Cronbach's alpha to make sense, all correlations between items should be > 0. This is because alpha is based on the classical test theory model of (essential) tau-equivalence. Essential tau-equivalence means the items measure a single common factor with equal unstandardized loadings. A necessary condition for essential tau-equivalence is that the items be positively correlated.  When you have negatively correlated items, something must have gone wrong with either the (re)coding of the items or there must be some other data- or measurement-related issue.

You should reverse code the items based on their content and relation to other variables, not whether the wording is negative or positive.  Suppose you had two questions (out of a longer survey):

How much do you dislike Donald Trump?
How much do you like Kamala Harris?

Each scored from 1 (not at all) to 5 (intensely).
One is negatively worded, but you would not want to reverse code it. Leave them as is.
That said, I have read some articles showing an effect of negatively worded items, but that is a separate point.
